# Abstract class not added to Create-view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've got a class in my model like so:

```
public class LikeSo
{
  public String Beep { get; set; }
  public String Meep { get; set; }
}
```

In the class I'm creating a view for, I've added it With a bunch of others.

```
public class BunchOfOthers
{
  ...
  public LikeSo LikieLikie { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

When I attempt to create a new *BunchOfOthers* instance, I'm getting the error that the *LikeSo* isn't instantiated. That's true and I know about the limitation of EF in that respect.

However, what I'd like to know is how I can automatically generate input boxes for *Beep* and *Meep*.

Comment: shouldn't your class properties virtual in order to be used by EF?

Comment: Maybe. But that's not the problem. Independently of whether they're *virtual* or not, the fields don't appear on the create view. The data consequently isn't bound and the crash occurs due to the object not being instantiated.

Comment: I dont think inner object will be instantiated unless u assign a value to it.

Comment: There's no assigning of ay value because the fields are not shown on the screen. If I instantiate the sucker by hand in the code, it works. But I'd like the boxes for input of data to be autogenerated for me when I create the controller and the view.

Comment: Hmm...but in any case you are instantiating the parent object while passing to the view. So whats wrong with assigning a value to inner object?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that. It just doesn't matter. The problem occurs when saving to the DB. And I'd like the boxes to fill out for the user to be created for the inner members as well. So the issue is rather - how do I make the IDE to automatically generate controls that can be used to specify the inner members when autogenerating a view/controller.